# How to set the right android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion for Android 5.0.2?

Tags: android

I'm getting a Parsing error from my React Native generated .apk file. So I'm trying changing the `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` in my manifest file.

My device is running Android 5.0.2. To what should I set those two options?

Comment: which IDE you are using right now? generally MinSdkVersion should be min API you want to support while targetSdkVersion should be max API that is 23 right now.

Comment: @Shvet I'm not using any IDE. I'm using React Native.

Comment: sorry dont have knowledge React!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `minSdkVersion` is minimum version of Android that you are going to support. If you don't need to support for pre-4.0 Android devices then recommended `minSdkVersion` is 16.

The `compileSdkVersion` is the version of the API the app is compiled against. It's recommended to use the latest one, which 23 for now.

The `targetSdkVersion` is supposed to indicate that you have tested your app on (presumably up to and including) the version you specify. So it's also should be the latest one.

Answer (score 2):

Android 5.0.2 is API level 21.

`android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` should be around them.
But include 21.

for example:

```
minSdkVersion = 15
targetSdkVersion = 22
```

Keep in mind, that some functions are not included in low API levels. if you set the Version in build.gradle, Android Studio will warn you if you want to use a function that's not supported in minSDKVersion.